# VBA- Import Multiple CSV to a Sheet, Remove Certain Rows/Columns

Tags: vba, csv

I am completely new to VBA, but I have CSV files(same format for all of them), and I want to import them to a single sheet on Excel. I was able to read the CSV file according to this code:

```
Sub R_AnalysisMerger()
Dim WSA As Worksheet
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim SelectedFiles() As Variant
Dim NFile As Long
Dim FileName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet, vDB As Variant, rngT As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Selects the CSV files as SELECTED FILES
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
ws.UsedRange.Clear  'Clears current worksheet
SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.csv*), *.csv*", MultiSelect:=True) 'Selects csv files


For NFile = LBound(SelectedFiles) To UBound(SelectedFiles)
    FileName = SelectedFiles(NFile)
    Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(FileName, Format:=2)
    Set WSA = bookList.Sheets(1)
    With WSA
        vDB = .UsedRange
        Set rngT = ws.Range("a" & Rows.count).End(xlUp)(2)
        If rngT.Row = 2 Then Set rngT = ws.Range("A1")
        rngT.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB

        bookList.Close (0)
    End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ws.Range("A1").Select
```

But I have additional requirements:
Skip the first column.
Skip the first four rows.
Remove a certain String from each word in the fifth row.

Im used to java, and usually I would read each line with a "for" loop and set "if" statements to skip the first row and four columns and remove the string from each string if it was present.

I don't know how to do this with this code. From what I understand it just copies the whole CSV file into the sheet?

Comment: Did you try using the Macro recorder?

Comment: @Sorceri Yes, I have no problem with removable the columns and lines, but the fifth line consists of "(Part A) some number (Part B)" I want to remove Part A and B, but the numbers can vary from file to file. When I tried recording a macro and removing the parts and pasting them into my active sheet, they just wrote the code as copy and pasting the number itself, rather than just removing the parts like I need

Comment: Are these parts in a separate cells or do you need to exclude parts of a string based on delimiters?  You will have to outline what the data you want to exclude (modify) on read looks like . . . .

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code Each cell in the fifth row has "Num 100 cm" and the parts I want to remove are Num and cm

Comment: you can REPLACE with "" (nothing) for those if found when you read the string making a new string.  You can read it all and then go in looking to modify after the read, or you could do it during the read.  Parsing is never fun, but it is very necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is based on reading CSV as textstream. I have tried to include feature that makes possible most all things like selecting columns, Rows and so on.

```
Sub ImportCSV()    

Dim fso As New IWshRuntimeLibrary.FileSystemObject
Dim txtStream  As IWshRuntimeLibrary.TextStream
Dim files As IWshRuntimeLibrary.files
Dim file As IWshRuntimeLibrary.file
Dim txtLine As String
Dim lineCount As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim lineCol As Variant
Dim rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).usedRange.Delete
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).usedRange
lastRow = 1
Set files = fso.GetFolder("path\folder").files

For Each file In files
    If file.Name Like "*.csv" Then
        Set txtStream = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading, TristateUseDefault)
        txtStream.SkipLine                                 ' skip first line, since it containes headers
        lineCount = 1
        Do
            txtLine = txtStream.ReadLine
            If lineCount = 5 Then
                txtLine = Replace(txtLine, "stringToReplace", "StringToReplcaeWith")    ' replace certain string from words in 5'th row
            End If
            lineCount = lineCount + 1
            lineCol = sliceStr(Split(txtLine, ";"), startIdx:=4)        ' slice the array so to skip four first columns
            For iCol = 0 To UBound(lineCol)                             ' write columns to last row
                rng(lastRow, iCol + 1).Value = lineCol(iCol)
            Next iCol
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
            'Debug.Print Join(lineCol, ";")                              ' debug
        Loop Until txtStream.AtEndOfStream
    End If
Next file
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This is the slicer function

```
Function sliceStr(arr As Variant, startIdx As Integer, Optional stopIdx As Integer = 0) As String()
        If stopIdx = 0 Then
           stopIdx = UBound(arr)
        End If
        Dim tempArrStr() As String
        ReDim tempArrStr(stopIdx - startIdx)
        Dim counter As Integer
        counter = 0
        For i = startIdx To stopIdx
            tempArrStr(counter) = arr(i)
            counter = counter + 1
        Next
        sliceStr = tempArrStr
End Function
```

Comment: When I tried testing this method it gave Highlighted the first line and gave me an Compile error: "User-defined type not defined"?

Comment: You have to include all the references needed. In this case it could be "Windows Script Host Object". Tools -> References -> enable: "Windows Script Host Object"

Answer (score 1):

I just did a simple test and the code below seems to work.  Give it a go, and feedback.

```
Sub Demo()
     Dim fso As Object 'FileSystemObject
     Dim fldStart As Object 'Folder
     Dim fld As Object 'Folder
     Dim fl As Object 'File
     Dim Mask As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Dim newWS As Worksheet

Set newWS = Sheets.Add(before:=Sheets(1))

    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject") ' late binding
     'Set fso = New FileSystemObject 'or use early binding (also replace Object types)

    Set fldStart = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\ryans\OneDrive\Desktop\output\") ' <-- use your FileDialog code here
     Mask = "*.csv"
     'Debug.Print fldStart.Path & ""
     ListFiles fldStart, Mask
     For Each fld In fldStart.SubFolders
         ListFiles fld, Mask
         ListFolders fld, Mask
     Next

Dim myWB As Workbook, WB As Workbook
 Set myWB = ThisWorkbook
 Dim L As Long, t As Long, i As Long
 L = myWB.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 t = 1
 For i = 1 To L
 Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=myWB.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
 Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
 lrow = WB.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 WB.Sheets(1).Range("B4:E" & lrow).Copy newWS.Cells(t, 2)
 t = myWB.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
 WB.Close False
 Next
 myWB.Sheets(1).Columns(1).Delete
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub



Sub ListFolders(fldStart As Object, Mask As String)
     Dim fld As Object 'Folder
     For Each fld In fldStart.SubFolders
         'Debug.Print fld.Path & ""
         ListFiles fld, Mask
         ListFolders fld, Mask
     Next
 End Sub



Sub ListFiles(fld As Object, Mask As String)
 Dim t As Long
     Dim fl As Object 'File
     For Each fl In fld.Files
         If fl.Name Like Mask Then
         t = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
             'Debug.Print fld.Path & "" & fl.Name
             If Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = "" Then
             Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = fld.Path & "\" & fl.Name
             Else
             Sheets(1).Cells(t, 1) = fld.Path & "\" & fl.Name
             End If
         End If
     Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the code it really provided a good base for me. The only thing I had to change was that I ended up using a separate function to open up a file selector and returning the file path as a String. It worked. The result was that the Column A and the first few rows were removed from every csv file as needed.  The problem is that only the first four columns after were printed into the sheet, but that was easy to fix. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: If it helps you, please go ahead and upvote this answer.  Thanks.